# In Gmail, when sending emails as another account yy@gmail, keep trace of these messages in yy@gmail?

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I have 2 email accounts with `gmail`; eg. first@gmail second@gmail, and. I am forwarding the emails from the first account to that of the second. I have a filter in the second account which labels the first account's incoming emails, and I can send emails from the second account as if they were originating from the first.

What is not happening is: when I send an email from the second account under the name of the first account, a copy of it is not kept under the first account's sent folder. So when I log into the account of the first email the transaction record is not kept.

I tried to do things like enable/create a POP3 connection but that did not work and am not sure if this was a path to a solution. I wonder if the ability to use an address as an **alias** would create such an action.

Answer (score 2):

Add the yy@gmail.com to TO, CC or BCC fields.